# Python - Win32Com - How to extract hyperlink from Excel spreadsheet cell?

Tags: python, excel, win32com, win32gui

I'm trying to get hyperlinks from individual cells in an excel spreadsheet with the following code:

```
import win32com.client 
import win32ui

app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
app.visible = True

workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.Sheets[0]
test_cell = sheet.Range("A8").value
```

This prints the following:

```
test_cell
u'Link title'
```

But when I try to extract the hyperlink it did not return the link/url in string format but a 'COMObject unknown':

```
test_cell = sheet.Range("A8").Hyperlinks
test_cell
<COMObject <unknown>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sheet.Range("A8").Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
```